# How to generate bootstrap columns 6-6 in Pug JS with data

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, pug

I'm starting with node [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/) framework and I came across this

I'm getting Category array from API and I'm trying to display that category a 6-6 column with bootstrap. but don't know how to implement.

My Pug is -

```
.col-lg-6
  each category in allCategory
    h6.text-uppercase #{category.name}
      each subcategory in category.subcategories
        li.megamenu-list-item
          a.megamenu-list-link(href='/')
            | #{subcategory.name}
.col-lg-6
```

And i wanted my output should be like this (after looping allCategory)-

```
<div class="col-lg-6"> //--> First 6 Column
  <h6 class="text-uppercase">Category Name 1</h6>
  <li class="megamenu-list-item">
    <a class="megamenu-list-link" href="/">Subcategory Name 1</a>
    <a class="megamenu-list-link" href="/">Subcategory Name 1</a>
  </li>
  <h6 class="text-uppercase">Category Name 2</h6>
  <li class="megamenu-list-item">
    <a class="megamenu-list-link" href="/">Subcategory Name 2</a>
    <a class="megamenu-list-link" href="/">Subcategory Name 2</a>
  </li>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6"> //--> Second 6 Column
  <h6 class="text-uppercase">Category Name 3</h6>
  <li class="megamenu-list-item">
    <a class="megamenu-list-link" href="/">Subcategory Name 3</a>
    <a class="megamenu-list-link" href="/">Subcategory Name 3</a>
  </li>
  <h6 class="text-uppercase">Category Name 4</h6>
  <li class="megamenu-list-item">
    <a class="megamenu-list-link" href="/">Subcategory Name 4</a>
    <a class="megamenu-list-link" href="/">Subcategory Name 4</a>
  </li>
</div>
```

for e.g. I wanted like this -
[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3SrW.png)

and i'm getting like this - 
[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74wur.png)

Comment: `.col-lg-6 .col-lg-6` Why it means ? Two level of div ?

Comment: yes, like <div class="col-lg-6"></div><div class="col-lg-6"></div>

Comment: So, You have 6 objects in `allCategory` ?

Comment: No, i have 4 objects in allCategory.. i am looping those objects..n i wanted the first 2 objects to be in first .col-lg-6 and other 2 objects in another .col-lg-6.. you can see the image i posted. @ŞivāSankĂr

Comment: What is the actual HTML output of your pug template, and what is the actual HTML you want to get?  Without that it is difficult to see exactly what your objective is from a pug syntax perspective.

Comment: Make sure your indented correctly, You code doesn't have any problem, Post your rendered HTML

Comment: thank you for replying.. i hope my question is clear now.

Comment: The question has no answers because you still haven't posted the requested actual/desired HTML outputs.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the very same challenge. I fixed it by correcting my code basing on [this advice](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-grid-system.php): In a grid layout, content must be placed inside the columns (.col and .col-*) **and only columns may be the immediate children of rows (.row)**. Also, rows should be placed inside a container (either fixed or fluid) for proper padding and alignment. Other than that, Pug is strict on indentation as you probably are already aware.